# regex match hyphen slash alphanumeric in parentheses

Tags: java, regex

I have a String to match with regex

> String str = "(1a/2s-/-)"

The conditions I need to get:

1. There has to be a parentheses
2. only alphanumeric dash and slash could be inside parentheses and it repeats

regex I have tried so far

> ([A-Za-z0-9]*/*[A-Za-z0-9]+)

Does anyone could help me solve this?

Comment: What are you referring too when you say it repeats?

Comment: all of it (alphanumeric dash and slash)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're missing is you need to escape the special characters that have meaning to a regular expression. Such as parenthesis, dashes and slashes.

`\([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/]+\)`

If you need to force that the string is nothing but this then make it looks like this:

`^\([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/]+\)$`

The `^` and the `$` mean it must start and end with this respectively.

---

**Broken down:**

`^` = Must start with
`\(` = An opening parenthesis
`[a-zA-Z0-9\-\/]+` = At least one or more alphanumeric chars, dashes or forward slashes
`\)` = A closing parenthesis
`$` = Must end with

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^\([A-Za-z0-9\-\/]+\)$
```

You need to escape parentheses and put slash and dash into your character set. `^` and `$` is optional if you want to match the string from the beginning to end.